# Usages du futur antérieur : « La nation tout entière aura perdu … »

Tags: temps-grammatical, futur, temps-composés

Je ne comprends pas l'usage du futur antérieur dans cette phrase :

> Imagine un seul instant qu'aucun engin de transport public ne circule
>   durant la journée. La nation tout entière **aura perdu** avec de
>   graves retombées au niveau du PNB.

Est-ce une supposition, un vrai futur ? Est-ce que le futur peut être remplacé par un conditionnel (*La nation tout entière perdrait avec de graves retombées au niveau du PNB*) ?

Answer (score 2):

Le [futur antérieur](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futur_ant%C3%A9rieur) a plusieurs utilisations.

Ici on pourrait « traduire » ainsi :

- (Imagine un seul instant) = « Si »
- (aucun engin de transport public ne circule durant la journée) =  « action »
- (La nation tout entière) = « sujet »
- (aura perdu avec de graves retombées au niveau du PNB) = « conséquence »

En concevant le sens de la phrase :

> Si aucun engin de transport public ne circule durant la journée, la nation tout entière **y perdrait** avec de graves retombées au niveau du PNB.

Suis-je claire ?

Comment: Oui, j'ai déjà les idées un peu plus claires, merci. Donc "aura perdu" pourrait effectivement etre remplacé par "perdrait" ? Si oui, pourquoi utiliser le futur antérieur? Pour élever le registre ?

Comment: *Perdrait* mets l'accent sur l'aspect hypothétique de la situation. *Aura perdu* le met plutôt sur la séquence des évènements (c.-à.-d. le fait que la perte fait suite à la disparition des transports en commun), et donc inéluctabilité de cette conséquence.